# Firebase setDoc() not creating document

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm creating a new user with auth which is working then taking that newly create uid to create a new document with the same.

```
const currentUser = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
        console.log('user registered')
        await setDoc(doc(db, "users", currentUser.user.uid),{
            forname: "Peter",
            surname: "Parker"
        })
        console.log('user profile added')
    dispatch({type:'USER_REG', payload: currentUser});
```

The reg process fires off without issue as I get the console log then the program just waits, its like setDoc is running but never completing and I have no idea why.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you set setDoc() anywhere?

Comment: I've imported it from firebase/firestore just like in the Firebase docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Comment: Can you provide the import code for calling your setDoc()? Additionally, can you please verify if you have enabled the Email/Password, and Anonymous sign-in providers in your Firebase Authentication?

Comment: Of course, the import code is "import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";" and I've got email/password enabled but not anonymous, think that could be the issue? I will say users can register fine and login with those credentials, the only issue is when I then try to create a doc, if that helps clear things up.

Comment: Thanks for this confirmation. Can you please also try to add a "catch" error: `setDoc(doc(db, "users", currentUser.user.uid),{forname: "Peter", surname: "Parker"}).catch((e) => {  console.log(e); })` in your setDoc()? For us to make sure that there's no error that's being thrown. Lastly, can you also show how you initialize your db in your setDoc()?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue with firebase firestore's setDoc() function
for me the problem was actually due to firestore rules being set too restrictively and not allowing to setdocs.

check the rules and adjust them:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, pass).then(async(userRec)=>{
    const user = userRec.user;
    await await setDoc(doc(db, "users", user.uid),{
        forname: "Peter",
        surname: "Parker"
    }).catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error);
    });
}).catch((error)=>{
    console.log(error);
});
```