# Firestore setDoc not creating document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

Trying to send the post data(title, text, etc.) to firestore when the user clicks 'Post' button. For that, I'm using `await setDoc()` function.

I'm expecting to see the post data in the firestore emulator, but it isn't showing any.

[image]*After I click the Post button, it doesn't navigate to the home page.*
[image]*But when I manually navigate to the home page, I can see the post, which means the post data is properly dispatched through redux.*

It doesn't seem to return any error message, but the code after the `await setDoc()` isn't implemented. Following is the code.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69457119/firebase-setdoc-not-creating-document) seems to be the same issue as mine, but the solution(adding `.catch((e) => {  console.log(e); })` after the `setDoc()`) doesn't seem to show any error message in the console.

```js
//firebase.js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: String(process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY),
  authDomain: String(process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN),
  projectId: String(process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID),
  storageBucket: String(process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET),
  messagingSenderId: String(process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID),
  appId: String(process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID),
  measurementId: String(process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_SENDER_ID)
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const auth = getAuth(app);
connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://localhost:9099");
export {
  auth,
  db,
}
export default app;


//CreatePost.tsx
...
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 
import { db } from '../firebase';
...
const handlePostClick = async () => {
    const postData: PostType = {
        postId: postId,
        title: title,
        text: text,
        voteCount: 0
      };
      try {
        // Dispatch an action to submit the post data
        dispatch(postSubmit(postData));
        // Save the post data to Firestore
        await setDoc(doc(db, "posts", postId), postData);
        // Reset the form fields
        setTitle('');
        setText('');
      
        // Navigate to the desired component
        navigate('/');
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error saving post to Firestore:', error);
      }
  };
```

FYI, I'm using "firebase": "^9.22.0", "react": "^18.2.0", "redux": "^4.2.1" and "redux-firestore": "^2.0.1".

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `alert('a')` will block code execution, have you tried removing the alerts before setDoc or dismissing it?

Comment: It still doesn't work. :/ It doesn't even navigate to the home page(`navigate('/');`)

Comment: Have you tried logging title? Is the `if (title)` block working or maybe try using and else block in case that title is undefined.

Comment: I've always entered the title, so that doesn't seem to be the cause. Also, it dispatched action and navigated to the home page just fine when I erased the line `await setDoc(doc(db, "posts", postId), postData)`, so I think the issue is with that specific line.

Comment: Please include where you're getting `db` from, what your initialization (with config) looks like, what command you use to start the emulators and finally the output of `firebase use`

Comment: Ofc - I'm getting `db` defined as `const db = getFirestore(app);` in firebase.js. The initialisation looks like `const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)`

Comment: Config is ```const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: String(process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY),
  authDomain: String(process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN),
  projectId: String(process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID),
  storageBucket: String(process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET),
  messagingSenderId: String(process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID),
  appId: String(process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID),
  measurementId: String(process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_SENDER_ID)
};```,

Comment: and the command I use to start the emulators is `firebase emulators:start`, which executes authentication, firestore and realtime database.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the right value for 'title'? If you log that do you see the value you expect? I'd add an `else` condition at that value just to make sure.

Comment: I tried after erasing the `if(title)` statement, but is still not working :/ I added screenshots of what I'm seeing for reference

Comment: seem like you are connected to auth emulator, if you want to set live database document and you have setup the rule to accept only authorized request, you cannot use emulator auth, you need to use live auth

Comment: Auth emulator is working just fine, but it's firestore emulator(+ `setDoc` function) that's not working. Then do you mean I need to deploy the project and get rid of the emulator environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR;

1. Make sure you connect the app to Firestore emulator using  `connectFirestoreEmulator`.
2. Check `firestore.rules` if the rule is `allow read, write: if true;`.

I had to add `connectFirestoreEmulator(db,'0.0.0.0', 8080)` in `firebase.js`,
and edit the firestore rules. Below is the modified code.

```js
//firebase.js
...

const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const auth = getAuth(app);
connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://localhost:9099");
connectFirestoreEmulator(db,'0.0.0.0', 8080) // Added this part
...

//firestore.rules
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```